# MacBook Pro Sluggish boot

Tags: startup

My MacBookPro has been extremely slow at the startup. Is there something similar to Window's System Registry that I can see all the boot files and uncheck what I don't need?

I'm running Mac OS X Version 10.6.8

- Model Name:  MacBook Pro
- Model Identifier: MacBookPro7,1
- Processor Name: Intel Core 2 Duo
- Processor Speed: 2.4 GHz
- Number Of Processors: 1
- Total Number Of Cores: 2
- L2 Cache: 3 MB
- Memory: 4 GB
- Bus Speed: 1.07 GHz
- Boot ROM Version: MBP71.0039.B0B
- SMC Version (system): 1.62f7

Comment: First boot in verbose mode and see what takes time - also what are you measuring the time to - getting the window to enter user name and password or until the users's programs have started

Answer (score 1):

try clearing temporary files and prefs (Note: do it within your user library not on system library. I had a bad experience with it before).